# Debug InputDevices process / xbox360 wired controller

Tags: game-controllers

- Wired xbox 360 controller - works fine on PC
- USB otg cable - my mouse works fine on the rooted phone (funny to have a mouse on a phone btw)
- Connecting controller to phone or tablet - nothing happens (on tablet I have USB plug notifications)
- Xbox 360 layout file is there (Vendor_045e_Product_028e.kl)

here:

```
#
# XBox 360 USB Controller
#

key 304   BUTTON_A
key 305   BUTTON_B
key 307   BUTTON_X
key 308   BUTTON_Y
key 310   BUTTON_L1
key 311   BUTTON_R1
key 314   BACK
key 315   BUTTON_START
key 316   HOME
key 317   BUTTON_THUMBL
key 318   BUTTON_THUMBR

# Left and right stick.
# The reported value for flat is 128 out of a range from -32767 to 32768, which is absurd.
# This confuses applications that rely on the flat value because the joystick actually
# settles in a flat range of +/- 4096 or so.
axis 0x00 X flat 4096
axis 0x01 Y flat 4096
axis 0x03 Z flat 4096
axis 0x04 RZ flat 4096

# Triggers.
axis 0x02 LTRIGGER
axis 0x05 RTRIGGER

# Hat.
axis 0x10 HAT_X
axis 0x11 HAT_Y
```

- The logcat provides me only this log when I plug the controller :

> 04-20 00:06:35.792: W/ContextImpl(2292): Calling a method in the
>   system process without a qualified user:
>   android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1187
>   com.android.server.usb.UsbSettingsManager.deviceAttached:621
>   com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.usbDeviceAdded:156
>   com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.monitorUsbHostBus:-2
>   com.android.server.usb.UsbHostManager.access$000:38

- Which links me to this code source page : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/services/java/com/android/server/usb/UsbSettingsManager.java

& this SO post which underlines somethings was not properly coded in the OS since it seems to raise a warning for everyone : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013787/using-sendbroadcast-in-a-system-app

- I will go pick up a keyboard and try to check the cable one more time, and I should probably try to find another controller pad.

Edit : New physical keyboard connects just fine, was able to type into the android, so the cable is not the issue at all.

Still **I want to understand why it is not working as intended**. any ideas on how to go down in the OS inner workings and see what is (not) happening?